# JQuery UI tabs using ajax to load document fragment

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using JQuery UI tabs and would like to load a fragment from a generated page. However, the whole page is loaded. Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
</head>


<div id="tabs">
<ul > 
    <li><a href="/page #content">Tab Head</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Also, is the Tabs plugin using .load() or .get() ajax calls?

Comment: A good question. What happens if you remove the space in your HREF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do it yourself by intercepting the desired tab and load the content in. For example, you could include the actual URL for loading the fragment to a data attribute, say, `data-content-url="/page #content"`, and load it in the `select` event. So, it would look something like:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var $tabAnchor = $(ui.tab);
        if (ui.index == 0 && !$tabAnchor.data('completed')) {
            $($tabAnchor.attr('href')).load($tabAnchor.data('content-url'), function() {
                // indicate the content has been loaded
                $tabAnchor.data('completed', true);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML would look something like:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs1" data-content-url="/page #content">Tab Head</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs1"></div>
    <div id="tabs2">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is still think there should be a more generic way to do this. Looking at the JQuery .load specification it should be easy to implement...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the load-event ("This event is triggered after the content of a remote tab has been loaded.") of the tabs to parse/prepare/edit the loaded content and get the fragment of the page.